# How to interpret this ROC AUC curve which does not start a zero

Tags: r, graph, naivebayes, roc, auc

I have a ROC curve which strangely does not start at 0 and was wondering what does this signify?
This ROC curve was generated from a Naive Bayes Classifier

Dataset can be downloaded from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14HG2sQDeAo8iPnYcZjEXvAi7iuimKwyD/view?usp=sharing

[image: r]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
mammographic_masses<- read_csv("MyData.csv")
set.seed(123)
training.samples <- mammographic_masses$severity %>%
    createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
trainData  <- mammographic_masses[training.samples, ]
testData <- mammographic_masses[-training.samples, ]
library(e1071)
nb_model = naiveBayes(as.factor(severity) ~., data=trainData)
nb_predicted <- predict(nb_model, testData)
nb_predicted <- as.numeric(levels(nb_predicted))[nb_predicted]
plotROC(testData$severity, nb_predicted)
```

Comment: Provide your "trainData" or an example of that, so we can replicate your plot, please.

Comment: I have provided my dataset

Comment: Your code isn't running. I edited it to add the obvious `library` calls, and I don't know why you had `col_names = FALSE` when you clearly used the columns by name. But still I get `Error: object 'plotROC' not found`. There are many packages providing this function, please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which package you are using that provides the `plotROC` function.

But the interpretation is clear: **it's a bug**.

A ROC curve **always** starts from the bottom left corner, and ends at the top right corner. Always. There is no exception to this rule.

Here is the correct ROC curve as calculated by the `pROC` package from your data:

```
library(pROC)
plot(roc(testData$severity, nb_predicted), print.auc = TRUE)
```

[image: The correct ROC curve]